# Docusign REST API attachment

Tags: rest, docusignapi

What I am trying is, send a document with an attachment placeholder to the recipients so that, when they open the DocuSign mail, they can able to attach additional documents.

What I have done is, created an envelope and get the `envelopId` in the response

```
{
  "status": "sent",
  "emailSubject": "Example of one recipient, type signer",
  "documents": [{
    "documentId": "1",
    "name": "contract.pdf",
    "documentBase64": "base64 document bytes...",
  }],
  "recipients": {
    "signers": [{
      "name": "Lisa Simpson",
      "email": "lisa@email.com",
      "recipientId": "1",
      "routingOrder": "1",
      "tabs": {
        "signHereTabs": [{
          "xPosition": "150",
          "yPosition": "200",
          "documentId": "1",
          "pageNumber": "1"
        }],
      }
    }]
  }
}
```

for attaching attachment, from the documentation I got

```
PUT /v2/accounts/{accountId}/envelopes/{envelopeId}/attachments
```

But, the thing I can not understand that, I create an envelope with a document and send it to the recipient, then I get an `envelopeId`

After that, why I should put the attachment placeholder? The envelope (DocuSign mail) already sent to the recipient.

How can I send an attachment placeholder via DocuSign REST API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Envelope Attachments are metadata.  I think you want to have the recipient upload and attach a file to the envelope?  To do so, you add a "signerAttachment" tab.  The tab will need to be placed somewhere on your document. The account configuration option to either append the uploaded file to the document hosting the signerAttachment tab or to add the file as another document in the envelope will affect how you get the uploaded document back.

```
"tabs": {
    "signHereTabs": [{
      "xPosition": "150",
      "yPosition": "200",
      "documentId": "1",
      "pageNumber": "1"
    }],
    "signerAttachmentTabs":[{
      "xPosition": "150",
      "yPosition": "500",
      "documentId": "1",
      "pageNumber": "1"
    }]
  }
```

Comment: Was this what you were looking for?